# Is my wireless adapter supported for monitoring?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, sniffing, network-monitoring

Ive recently bought a https://www.amazon.co.uk/AC1200Mbps-Wireless-Antennas-802-11ac-MacOS10-5-14/dp/B07PQJYLDH/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=high+gain+dual+antenna&qid=1562166711&s=gateway&sr=8-1
and when i was testing in Microsoft Network Monitor it didnk work.
Is the device supported for monitoring?

[img of device manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk0HI.png)
[img of microsoft network monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLzxe.png)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the question and what have you tried?

Comment: And we don't know what chipset it has. Please check device manager, then [edit] and update the question accordingly.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia, with a quick search it looks like the chipset is a **rtl-8812BU**.

Comment: i just finished editing

Comment: @xpkiro ive added new info